# how to send large amount of data to the back end?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am relatively new to full stack development 
i am building an application where i have send a large amount of data (10 to 20 MB) to back end(nodejs express server) from the front end (react) but when i send that via axios it at the back end i could only get 20% of the total data.

### node js code

```
app.post("/download",function(request,response,next){    
    let sheets=request.body["sheets"];
    console.log(sheets);
```

### react code

```
 handleSaveAs=function(){


    let data=new FormData();
    data.append('sheets',JSON.stringify(this.state));
    console.log(this.state);
    axios
    .post("http://localhost:4001/download",data)
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      const element = document.createElement("a");
      const file = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'text/plain'});
      element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      element.download = "untitled.txt";
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();
    })


  }
```

Comment: Have you check on your server if there are limits on the max body size? Try out the same request via curl or some client like postman and see how that responds.

Comment: would help if you add information about the server, is it just a node application, is it behind nginx or something like that? also, that is weird that only 20% get sent, are there any logs in the server? do you see anything weird in the inspector on ur browser?

Comment: Maybe give WebSocket a try?